# localhost CORS error using Flask and React

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, api, flask, cors

I am having some trouble with the development of my React app. On the client side, I'm using Axios to make the requests to the API (Flask).

The problem is that I frequently get a CORS error only when I send the request to the localhost API. I have the same API running in Heroku without any error.

> API route = *http://127.0.0.1:5000*

> Client route = *http://localhost:3000/#/*

### Client code:

```
const endpoint = process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT;
// Fetch API data
const [data, setData] = useState([{}]);
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(endpoint + "/api/rooms")
        .then((data) => {
            console.log("API endpoint data retrieved.");
            if (data[200] !== "No Rooms") {
                setData(data);
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(err.message);
            console.log("No rooms retrieved from API endpoint.");
        });
}, [endpoint]);
```

### Server (Python) code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from app_modules.util.rooms import Rooms

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="/client/build")
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv("app_key")
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = "Content-Type"
ALLOWED_ORIGINS = os.getenv("ALLOWED_ORIGINS")

cors = CORS(app, resources={"/*": {"origins": ALLOWED_ORIGINS}}, support_credentials=True)

socketio = SocketIO(app,
                    cors_allowed_origins=ALLOWED_ORIGINS,
                    logger=False,
                    engineio_logger=False,
                    cors_credentials=True)

rooms = Rooms()


@app.route('/api/rooms')
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def home():
    return {"rooms": rooms.secure_api} if rooms.secure_api else {"200": "No Rooms"}
```

**Note:**
ALLOWED_ORIGINS=*

### But I keep getting this error:

[image: console error]

[image: network console]

Comment: What is the current value of `ALLOWED_ORIGINS`?

Comment: ALLOWED_ORIGINS=*

Answer (score -1):

In your server code change

```
ALLOWED_ORIGINS = os.getenv("ALLOWED_ORIGINS")
```

to

```
ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I get the same error.